# Where to put a PAM module?

Tags: c, linux, pam

I'm currently trying to test a PAM module, this one: http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-example.html.

There is no indication about where to put the `.o` file.

I tried to put it in `/lib/security` and `/usr/lib/security` but it doesn't work.

I had no error while compiling:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -c check_user.c
$ ld -x --shared -o check_user.so check_user.o
```

As indicated, I put those lines in `/etc/pam.d/check_user`:

```
auth       required     pam_unix.so
account    required     pam_unix.so
```

It doesn't seem to work because when I try to log in with another account I don't have the message. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who want to create a PAM module, there is a very good example here: https://github.com/beatgammit/simple-pam.

In my case, the functions to call in my PAM module to exec something at login/logout are:

```
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_open_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int  flags,int argc, const char **argv ) {
    printf("Connected\n");
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_close_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int  flags,int argc, const char **argv ) {
    printf("Disconnected\n");
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

As indicated in the `README`, the `so` file needs to be put into `/lib/security/`.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are linking is not a pam module, is just a short application written in C that uses pam_unix.so. You have to compile and run check_user.

Actually, you are browsing the Linux PAM Application Developer's Guide, you may want to check the guide to modules development: http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_MWG.html

If you need to start an application on logon (as stated in your comment) and you want to use pam, you can relay on pam_exec (http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec).

Add this line to /etc/pam.d/login:

```
session         optional        pam_exec.so /usr/local/bin/my_prog
```

See also this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/execute-a-command-on-user-logon

Comment: The thing is that it's useless in my case to run check_user manually. I want it to run automatically when a user log in. If I have to do it manually I don't understand why I have to put those two lines in `/etc/pam.d/check_user`.

Comment: This is just a sample to understand how to include pam calls in a C. You should not use it in a production system. Starting an application on log in is a completely different question.

Comment: Actually you can also use pam to customise the login. I am editing my answer.